# PHPExcel return only empty cell values

Tags: php, phpexcel

I start with these code

```
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize' => '128MB');
$cacheEnabled = PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
if (!$cacheEnabled)
{
            # WARNING - Cache to php temp not enableable ###" . PHP_EOL;
}
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($file_path);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);  
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file_path);
$objWorksheet   = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

Then

```
 $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
```

returns 2560. Ok, I've an excel with 2560 rows populated.

Then I loop

```
for ($x =1; $x<=$highestRow; $x++)  // here $x plus plus ...
{
   $ean                = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(15, $row)->getValue();
   $description        = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(13, $row)->getValue();
   echo $ean .":" .$description . PHP_EOL;
}
```

But every row is empty, only 2560 ":" are printed.

So I'd like to dump entire row because I really cannot understand why returned value are empty! Every single cell of sheet, from A to BC, from 1 to 2560, are filled with some value.

Why all of cells look like empty?
How to debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$row` to reference the row in your call to `getCellByColumnAndRow()`, but it isn't defined anywhere as your for loop is using `$x`

Either

```
for ($x =1; $x<=$highestRow; $x++)
{
   $ean                = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(15, $x)->getValue();
   $description        = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(13, $x)->getValue();
   echo $ean .":" .$description . PHP_EOL;
}
```

or

```
for ($row =1; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
{
   $ean                = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(15, $row)->getValue();
   $description        = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(13, $row)->getValue();
   echo $ean .":" .$description . PHP_EOL;
}
```